# OnItemClickListener with multiple viewType in adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an Adapter with multiple view type defined like that

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    ...
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
        return (bool()) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int type = getItemViewType(i);
        if (type == 1) {
            return viewType(R.layout.list_item_ads_alert, i, view, viewGroup);
        }
        else {
            return viewType(R.layout.list_item_ads, i, view, viewGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

then in my fragment I instantiate it and set it to a listView,
plus I add an onItemClick listener to it

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("app", "pushed item " + i);
    }
});
```

The problem is that my ItemClickListener is NOT called when I click on an item of the second view type, but it works for the first view type

Do you know if there is a specific way to do ItemClick for this case?
Of course I can add a onClick to the second view type but it seems not right (code separation)

Comment: what do you see in the log? nothing when you click on second view?

Comment: I see nothing on the log for the second type view. If let say I have 3 view of first type one of second and 1 off first like 1 1 1 2 1, if I click on each one i'll have item 1, item 2, item 3, nothing, item 5 (so the count is incremented)

Comment: implement OnClickListener in Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 2nd view type contains a checkbox or a button, that widget is stealing focus from the parent view, and not allowing the parent view to be clicked. In order to prevent this from happening, in your root layout of your 2nd view type you should put

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

so that child views are not able to steal the focus of the parent.

Comment: I think you are on something, I do have a button on the second view type. Let me test your answer